# How to stop Laravel from starting queues automatically?

Tags: laravel, forge, laravel-queue

I use Forge for my laravel builds and I want to use Forge queues to manage my workers.

However my problem is that Laravel automatically starts the queues when I restart server and I'm not sure what triggers them to start automatically.

Could it be that redis server starts the queues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had supervisor setup /etc/supervisor/conf.d/ deleting worker files from the folder helped.